# pyinstaller 3.2 build pyqt4/python2.7 to onefile exe, can not run missing msvcr100.dll?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, pyinstaller

As title,

Build successful, but the exe can't run. can not found msvcr100.dll.

I can put msvcr100.dll with exe in the same dir, the exe can run.

But I just want only one exe file.

Anyone know how to do?

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (or some other version depending on python version) is needed in any case, python27.dll requires it.

Answer (score 1):

Has solved.  This is a bug of pyinstaller3.2, the new in the git has solved this bug. Down the newest source in the github, erverything works fine.

Comment: thanks I have the same problem ... now I added the command to install direct from github `pip install git+git://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller`

Answer (score 1):

> Has solved. This is a bug of pyinstaller3.2, the new one in the git has solved this bug. Down the newest source in the GitHub, everything works fine.

This is correct, I cant tell you how much that answer helped me out. I have been trying to build a single exe Exploit to execute on Windows XP with-out it crashing for my OSCP Labs/Exam. I followed so many tutorials and nothing seems to work. I was able to build the EXE but could not get it to run under a single EXE.

If anyone who reads this is getting "This Program cannot be run in DOS mode" try running it from another machine with the same build (Windows XP). There is not much info out there on how to solve that from a Reverse Shell on a End Of Life Operating System using an EXE exploit built with Pyinstaller. (Lots of Trial and Error and determination)

> Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (or some other version depending on python version) is needed in any case, python27.dll requires it

I was also receiving an error about msvcr100.dll when ran from the GUI on my build machine(WinXP SP2). This is corrected in the 3.3 Dev version on GitHub.
I installed the C++ 2008 Package but this didn't solve my problem when I re-built the EXE, the 3.3 Dev Pyinstaller was the solution.

#### What I did was:

Zip down the Dev version of Pyinstaller 3.3 Dev(GitHub) is the newest for 11/14/16 that I could tell. Make sure you have Python 2.7.x (I used 2.7.11) and pywin32 installed that matches (Python 2.7.x) version. (And it does matter if its 64-bit or 32-bit) Use the setup.py to install Pyinstaller, make sure you do not have a previous version already installed, if so use pip or etc. to remove. ***I installed with pip first and this was my whole issue.***

I was able to get all of my 32-bit Single EXE Exploits to run on 64-bit/32-bit Windows machines up to Windows 10.

Once that is completed, make sure Pyinstaller is in your $PATH and follow the standard tutorials on creating a --onefile EXE. Copy to your Windows Target machine and it should work with-out error. I did not need to pull any dependencies over but you may have to include some with the --hidden command. Its greatly detailed in the Pyinstaller documentation on how to include hidden .dlls

If this still doesn't work for you try using py2exe. Its a little more complicated but it your determined you will figure it out.

If you have code written in python 2.x.x and 3.x.x you can have multiple environments of Python and have Pyinstaller installed in each. This is in the documentation as well.

***Thank you jim ying. Your 2 sentence answer was exactly what I needed.***