# Pyinstaller working in some computers other not

Tags: pyinstaller

I have a program that I created with pyinstaller using qt5, I converted the gui file into a py file

So I noticed the problem when I added a function and passed the program to others computers that I have, when I run the program to see that everything is good I found that in almost all the computers runs just fine while in 2 does not run, appears the message

```
pyinstaller failed to execute script
```

Just in case I always leave the previous version I created in the computer before deleting them, and I found that the previous version is not working in those computers as well

I generated the file again but now without the `--noconsole` parameter, and added `--debug=all`

And the program runs just fine, no errors, nothing so I'm at a loss of what is the problem with the computer

edit:
forgot to mention but im also using Opencv, the program is compiled in python 3.7 and the OS is windows 10 64x

Comment: Your question has aleady answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190861/exe-created-by-pyinstaller-runs-on-one-machine-but-gives-error-on-another

Comment: hi so the problem could be because some dll where deleted?

then how come if i run the program in debug mode it works in the computer that was not working, also forgot to mention it but i can only access the program doing double click